# Unable to resume from suspend after prolonged time

Tags: 20.04, suspend, hibernate

I appreciate there are a lot of existing questions on here about suspend and resume not working. However I cannot find anything which matches my particular problem.

Suspend and resume **does work** on my system with a gap of around 5 minutes and overnight (24 hours). However **after** 2 days resume no longer works. I have not tested longer periods of time.

I have an AMD Ryzen 7 3700X in an X570 motherboard, my OS is LUKS encrypted (via the installer). I am running Kubuntu 20.04 with all updates applied as of writing.

When trying to wake the system after 2 days, I tap the power button to wake it up, the power LED turns on, the fans spin up but the screens do not turn on and mouse/keyboard input does nothing. I cannot SSH to the machine either in this state. However, weirdly, the machine does respond to ping, which it definitely does not do while asleep. At this point I have to press the reset button to hard reset the system so I can use it again, which is really irritating.

Checking my syslog after a hard reset shows no entries at all after the final log message indicating the system is asleep 2 days prior until the first boot messages when I reset the machine. So I'm completely clueless what could be going wrong.

I tried adding `AllowHibernation=no` in `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` as I have 2GB swap and 32GB RAM which means hibernate obviously doesn't work. However this hasn't appeared to have helped.

As a side note, I have an Intel machine also running Ubuntu 20.04 LUKS encrypted on which suspend and resume works perfectly. Both the AMD and Intel machines are fresh installs of 20.04 and not upgraded from a previous version.

Update: ok now I'm even more confused, left it overnight and it woke up fine. Put it back to sleep for roughly 12 hours and same problem resuming.

Comment: It's a desktop on mains power. Also see update above

Comment: It's a brand new SSD and I've already memtested the RAM overnight with no issues. However I have managed to perfectly reproduce the problem.

Regardless of time, if a specific one of my 3 Dell monitors is not set to the correct input, the issue occurs. I've only just realised this today. I regularly change inputs on my monitors. Neither of my other 2 Dell monitors cause resume to fail if they are on the wrong input. This is even more puzzling.

Comment: I am glad you figured out how to reproduce the problem. You may want to file a bug report.

Comment: To whom? Ubuntu or the Linux kernel? Or someone else entirely? I'm still not sure what component is at fault

Comment: Please report to Ubuntu. They will escalate to kernel if needed. See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)